# Use of regex in bash with mv

Tags: regex, bash, file-rename, batch-rename, mv

I have 4 files to rename:

```
./01:
I0010001  I0020001

./02:
I0010001  I0020001
```

I want to add auxiliary filename `.dcm` to each file, so I have tried:

```
$ mv \(*/*\) \1.dcm
mv: cannot stat '(*/*)': No such file or directory

$ mv \(./*/*\) \1.dcm
mv: cannot stat '(./*/*)': No such file or directory

$ mv \(./\*/\*\) \1.dcm
mv: cannot stat '(./*/*)': No such file or directory

$ mv "\(./*/*\)" "\1.dcm"
mv: cannot stat '\(./*/*\)': No such file or directory

$ mv 0\([1-2]\)/I00\([1-2\)]0001 0\1/I00\20001.dcm
mv: cannot stat '0([1-2])/I00([1-2)]0001': No such file or directory

$ mv "0\([1-2]\)/I00\([1-2\)]0001" "0\1/I00\20001.dcm"
mv: cannot stat '0\([1-2]\)/I00\([1-2\)]0001': No such file or directory

$ mv "0\([1-2]\)/I00\([1-2]\)0001" "0\1/I00\20001.dcm"
mv: cannot stat '0\([1-2]\)/I00\([1-2]\)0001': No such file or directory

$ mv "0\([[:digit:]]\)/I00\([[:digit:]]\)0001" "0\1/I00\20001.dcm"
mv: cannot stat '0\([[:digit:]]\)/I00\([[:digit:]]\)0001': No such file or directory

$ mv "0\([1-2]\)\/I00\([1-2]\)0001" "0\1/I00\20001.dcm"
mv: cannot stat '0\([1-2]\)\/I00\([1-2]\)0001': No such file or directory

$ mv \(*\) \1.dcm
mv: cannot stat '(*)': No such file or directory
```

None of them yield the result I want.

Comment: So you know: your issue here is that these are not regexes: a star in bash uses [globbing](https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob). The particular difference here is that there are no capturing groups: the parenthesis are just seen as literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need regular expressions here, this is very simple with a `for` loop:

```
for f in 0[12]/I00[12]0001 ; do mv "$f" "${f}.dcm" ; done
```

For more complex situations, you should be looking into the `rename` program (`prename` on some systems), which uses powerful Perl regular expressions to handle the renaming. Though unnecessary here, this simple case would use:

```
pax> rename -n 's/$/.dcm/' 0[12]/I00[12]0001
rename(I01/I0010001, I01/I0010001.dcm)
rename(I01/I0020001, I01/I0020001.dcm)
rename(I02/I0010001, I02/I0010001.dcm)
rename(I02/I0020001, I02/I0020001.dcm)
```

That `-n` is debug mode (print what would happen but don't *actually* rename). Remove it once you're happy it will do what you want.

Comment: This does not really answers the question. Maybe leaving the troubleshooting as an observation and mainly explaining how to use regex with `mv` would be better

Comment: @LTKills, while the question *title* asks for a regex way, it is (like so many XY problems) totally unnecessary. The *actual* problem is how to rename files in a specific way. It's no different to if someone asked how to write an accounting package in assembler, an operating system in COBOL, or *anything* in PHP :-)

Comment: I agree with @gmelodie . The title "Use of regex in bash with mv" expects an answer related to that specific problem.

Comment: @Sylvain, if you ask a carpenter how to cut some wood with a hammer, only the most sadistic or deranged ones would suggest anything other than putting down the hammer and using a saw instead :-) The *problem* here is not how to use `mv` (despite what it looks like), it's how to rename files in a certain way. I would suggest the OP also came around to that way of thinking, as they accepted the answer.